# Iterate through rows in DataFrame and perform diff method only if values in a column are identical

Tags: python, pandas

I want to iterate through the rows in a DataFrame and perform the `df.columnB.diff()` method **only if** the current row and the next row have the same string in `df['columnA']`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `groupby`

```
df['New']=df.groupby('columnA')['columnB'].diff()
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize these methods can be used together :)